# why dynamically set text to TextView not visible in popup window while hard coded is

Tags: android

I am trying to generate popup window containing dynamically generated text. log output clearly shows that the desired text is actually set to textView but I can't understand why it is not showing on the app.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_parent_layout);
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.info_button){

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Updating a textview in different layout xml from the main activity
        LinearLayout vi = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_info, null);
        TextView textView = vi.findViewById(R.id.info);
        textView.setText(R.string.main_activity_info);
        Log.i("MainActivity",String.valueOf(textView.getText()));

        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_info,null);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        //Note showAtLocation method should always in end for proper rendering of poup Window
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout,Gravity.TOP,0,100);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

activity_info.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

popup window show hello which is hardcoded text.

Comment: you forgot this        popupWindow.setContentView(layout);

Comment: you inflate the same layout two times

Comment: Thanks for coming to rescue. I got my problem sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating `R.layout.activity_info` two times and losing the `TextView` you are changing in the process. Make the following change to keep the first inflation and your modification:

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(vi, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

Comment: Awesome man that worked I will try not to make silly mistakes like this. Thanks a lot.